# Failed connecting ssh with port number in CentOS 5.5

Tags: ssh

The server using CentOS 5.5

after changing default port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, Im restarting SSH using command

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

and then I'm exit

```
exit
```

So Im testing connect SSH `ssh -l root 123.456.789.123`
and quickly get a message which showing the modification I make giving an effect:

```
ssh: connect to host 123.456.789.123 port 22: Connection refused
```

Im trying to connect with port:

```
ssh -p 12345 -l root 123.456.789.123
```

It takes too long time, and then fail to connect with message:

```
ssh: connect to host 123.456.789.123 port 12345: Connection timed out
```

I think something wrong with my command to connect to the port. Using 
`ssh -l root 123.456.789.123`
 quickly giving error 
`ssh: connect to host 123.456.789.123 port 22: Connection refused`, 
while using 
`ssh -p 22 -l root 123.456.789.123` 
takes too long time and failed to connect with message 
`ssh: connect to host 123.456.789.123 port 12345: Connection timed out`

After reboot the server, this still happening

Answer (score 3):

CentOS by default has the iptables firewall running. You probably need to open the new port for ssh.

Edit the file /etc/sysconfig/iptables and find the line (or similar)

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

change the `22` to the port number you have chosen for your sshd e.g.

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
```

save the file and restart the iptables service

```
sudo service iptables restart
```

EDIT

Using iptables commands

Saved the current state of the firewall

```
sudo service iptables save
```

list the rule numbers for the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT table

```
sudo iptables -L RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  --line numbers
```

make a note of the line number for allowing ssh on port 22 on my system it's 12.

```
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
```

insert the new rule before the old one using for example port 12345

```
sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 12 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
```

Delete the old rule which will now be 1 higher than it was as the new rule went in before it but you can check by listing the line numbers like above.

```
sudo iptables  -D RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 13
```

save the new configuration

```
sudo service ipatbles save
```

Comment: but I cannot login through SSH and I'm doing all things remotely. this is new server without anything installed

Comment: You can't log in to the system at all now ?

Comment: How was the server rebooted? Is there someone on site who can do the editing at the console?

Comment: It may work, but /etc/sysconfig/iptables is **NOT** intended to be hand-edited. The correct way to change it is to modify you firewall using normal iptables commands, and then `service iptables save`.

Comment: @lain, yes.. except reboot the server through client dashboard and contact the support team

Comment: @maksi1: You should contact support now :(